# what is the best algorithm for this game?

Tags: algorithm, game-theory

I want to make a bot for this game:

The game is played with 8 cards, numbered 1 to 8. At the start of the game , these cards are all on the table (desk), faced up. Quoted from the instructions:

> The goal of the game is that you reach the sum of 15 with 3 cards in your hand. The first person to reach this goal in a maximum of 30 turns is the winner.
>
> Each time at your turn, you are supposed to take one card from the desk.
> When you have 3 cards in your hand, you should swap one of your cards in your hand with a card on the desk.

[image: game rules image]

All cards are visible to both players at all times.

What is the best algorithm to win the game?

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried. Also it would be helpful to know what language/framework you intend to use.

Comment: i want to write it with python and i tried to write it but it fails

Comment: Are all cards visible?

Comment: yes you can see what numbers are in desk and what numbers you have and what numbers enemy have

Comment: For each state after the pickup phase, find out if it's a win for player 1 or player 2 or a draw. There's only choose(8, 3) * choose(5, 3) = 560 states. Then solve the pickup phase, with the aim of that game to end up in a winning state as found earlier.

Comment: It's not *nearly* as simple, because the players won't always have 3 cards on their hand and you have to differentiate between the case in which it is one player's turn and when it is the other player's turn, but yes, the number of possibilities is computationally small.

Comment: is it a good idea to have all possible win states and check enemy cards with it and get the card that enemy wants to win?

Comment: Yes, if you see a possibility that the enemy would win if they picked a certain card, you are essentially forced to pick that card for yourself (or keep it in case it's already in your hand), lest you let the enemy win. This *may* lead to an endless cycle, which would be the non-losing strategy. What we want to know is whether there exists a winning strategy for either player, which means that the player can play in a way which will force a win for them, no matter what the other player picks.

Comment: I would implement the game and than try to implement different strategies to test them against each other and against humans.

Comment: Could you please clarify what *"get to 15"* means? Do I win if the sum of my cards is larger than 15? Or should it be exactly 15?

Comment: Well, if it was the first case (greater than 15) then the game is trivial. First player picks 8, second player picks 7 (they're forced to do so). Then the first player picks 6, and whatever the second player picks, the first player wins in the third turn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest creating a minimax algorithm, which is (like @PaulHankin's answer) creating a game tree. The difference is that the states are *discovered* as moves are played.

This question grabbed my interest, and so I had some fun in creating an interactive snippet in JavaScript. It shows you which moves are available, and whether they lead to a win, a loss or a draw. In the case of a win or loss, it tells you how many half-moves (plies) you are away from that fate (with optimal play).

Enjoy:

```js
class Node {
    constructor(id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.neighbors = []; // List of Node instances that can be reached with one move
    }
    cardOwner(card) {
        return (this.id >> (2*card-2)) & 3; // Decode binary representation
    }
    * generateMoves() { // Yield the moves that player 1 can make
        let hands = [[], [], []];
        // Translate id to sets of cards
        for (let card = 1; card <= 8; card++) hands[this.cardOwner(card)].push(card);
        let [desk, myHand, otherHand] = hands;
        if (otherHand.length < 3 || otherHand.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) !== 15) {
            if (myHand.length < 3) {
                for (let card of desk) yield this.getTargetId(card);
            } else {
                for (let discard of myHand) {
                    for (let replace of desk) yield this.getTargetId(discard, replace);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    getTargetId(...cards) {
        let id = this.id;
        for (let card of cards) id ^= 1 << (card*2-2);
        // Toggle owner, as in each state we consider player 1 as the player to move
        for (let mask = 3; mask < 0x10000; mask <<= 2) {
            if (id & mask) id ^= mask;
        }
        return id;
    }
    compare(next) {
        let id = this.id;
        let nextId = next.id;
        let diff = { replace: 0, discard: 0 };
        for (let card = 1; card <= 8; card++) {
            if ((id & 3) && !(nextId & 3)) diff.discard = card;
            else if (!(id & 3) && (nextId & 3)) diff.replace = card;
            id >>= 2;
            nextId >>= 2;
        }
        return diff;
    }
}

class Game {
    constructor() {
        this.hist = []; // Previous states (after moves have been made)
        this.node = new Node(0); // 0 is the initial state where all 8 cards are on desk
        this.visited = new Map; // Evaluated states; Node instances keyed by their identifier
    }
    move(target) {
        this.hist.push(this.node);
        this.node = target;
    }
    undo() {
        this.node = this.hist.pop();
    }
    minimax() {
        if (this.node.value !== undefined) return; // Already visited
        // Generate neighbors for this Node
        this.node.neighbors = Array.from(this.node.generateMoves(), targetId => {
            let target = this.visited.get(targetId); // Get a Node instance
            if (!target) this.visited.set(targetId, target = new Node(targetId));
            return target;
        });
        if (!this.node.neighbors.length) { // Game over!
            this.node.value = 100;
            return;
        }
        // Assign temporary value while depth-first search is ongoing.
        // This will ensure that a revisit is considered a draw (repetition of moves)
        this.node.value = 0; // 0 indicates a draw
        let bestValue = -Infinity;
        for (let target of this.node.neighbors) {
            this.move(target);
            this.minimax();
            bestValue = Math.max(bestValue, this.node.value);
            this.undo();
        }
        // Definite value: reduce its absolute value, so to favour quick wins over slow wins
        this.node.value = bestValue && (Math.abs(bestValue) - 1) * Math.sign(-bestValue);
    }
}

let game = new Game;
game.minimax();  // Create the full game tree rooted at the initial state

// I/O management

let state = document.getElementById("state");
let moves = document.getElementById("moves");
let undo = document.getElementById("undo");
let message = document.getElementById("message");

function display() {
    let turn = game.hist.length % 2;
    let mapper = [1, turn*2, 2 - turn*2];
    for (let card = 1; card <= 8; card++) {
        let owner = game.node.cardOwner(card);
        let ownerRow = state.rows[mapper[owner]];
        for (let row of state.rows) {
            row.cells[card].textContent = row === ownerRow ? card : "";
        }
    }
    state.rows[0].classList.toggle("turn", !turn);
    state.rows[2].classList.toggle("turn", turn);
    message.textContent = game.node.neighbors.length ? `Player ${turn + 1} to play. Make your choice:` : `Player ${2 - turn} won!`;
    undo.disabled = !game.hist.length;
    moves.innerHTML = "";
    for (let target of game.node.neighbors) {
        let { discard, replace } = game.node.compare(target);
        let button = document.createElement("button");
        button.textContent = `${discard ? `Replace ${discard} with` : "Select"} ${replace} ${
            target.value < 0 ? `(lose in ${101+target.value})` : 
            target.value > 0 ? `(win in ${101-target.value})` : "(draw)"
        }`;
        moves.appendChild(button);
    }
}

moves.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    let moveIndex = [...moves.children].indexOf(e.target);
    if (moveIndex >= 0) game.move(game.node.neighbors[moveIndex]);
    display();
});

undo.addEventListener("click", function() {
    game.undo();
    display();
});

display();
```

```css
td { border: 1px solid; background: yellow; min-width: 1em; text-align: center }
td:empty, td:first-child { border-color: transparent; background: none }
tr:nth-child(odd) { background: lightblue } 
tr.turn { background: orange }
#moves > * { display: block }
```

```html
<table id="state">
    <tr>
        <td>Player 1: </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Desk: </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Player 2: </td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<div id="message"></div>
<button id="undo">Undo last move</button><br>
<div id="moves"></div>
```

#### Remarks

The game is a draw when both players play optimally. The first player has a bit of an advantage if we consider that the second player has to be more careful in the first phase of the game not to make a mistake.

When the first player picks either card 6 or 8, the second player *must* take card 5 or they will lose (with optimal play). The game tree widens quickly, but there are other states where there is only one good move.

The number of distinct states that are discovered, including the root state, is 1713. The algorithm does not take the 30-move limit into account, as it is a "boring" rule. The nice thing of *not* having this limit is that the algorithm needs to be smart enough to detect repetitions. With the 30-move limit, such cycle check does not need to be implemented.

#### Python

The same implementation (interacting on console) can be found on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma690422495459839)

Comment: Ah, I assumed that you had to have 3 cards that sum to 15 to win. It's an ambiguity in the question.

Comment: The linked image in the question has the actual rules of the game, where it's unambiguously stated that you need to have 3 cards that sum to 15 to win.

Comment: Ah that's what happens when a question has not all info embedded in it.

Comment: With that new understanding I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can express the game as a directed graph, with nodes being states in the game, and edges being moves.

Then, you can mark terminal winning and losing states (ie: ones where one of the players has reached 15) as wins or losses. (And some states are "impossible" where both players have reached 15).

Then, you can repeatedly iterate through all states, marking states as wins if there's a winning move, and marking states as losing if all moves are losing. You repeat until no state changes from unknown to winning or losing.

In games like this one, it's possible for some states to be draws since it's possible to repeat game states. That's true here, so it may be that when you have finished iteration, some states are neither marked as wins or loses. Those are draws by repetition.

Normally when solving a game you have to do the iteration efficiently. Here, the total number of states is 1769 which is relatively small, so just iterating through all states each time is fine.

At the end of this answer is code that solves the game and [prints the optimal strategy](https://gist.github.com/paulhankin/ecb62eab078ce15ef08eef97441da419).

In the strategy, the player to move is listed first.

For example this line from the strategy:

```
128 - 346  : WINS: 1->5 | LOSSES: 1->7, 2->7, 8->5, 8->7 | DRAWS: 2->5
```

means that the player to move has cards [1, 2, 8] and their opponent has cards [3, 4, 6]. The player to move can win by discarding the 1 and picking up 5, the player on move can draw (with optimal play from both players) if they discard 2 and pick up 5, and otherwise the other player can force a win.

The first line:

```
/ - /  : WINS: none | LOSSES: none | DRAWS: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
```

means that in the initial state (`/` denotes holding no cards), then no matter what card you pick up the game is a draw given optimal play.

```
import itertools

def states():
    N = set(range(1, 9))
    for k in range(7): # total number of cards picked up.
        for p1 in itertools.combinations(N, k//2):
            for p2 in itertools.combinations(N.difference(p1), (k+1)//2):
                yield p1, p2

STATES = list(states())

PICKUPS = dict(((p1, p2), set(range(1, 9)).difference(p1).difference(p2)) for p1, p2 in STATES)
WL = dict()

def moves(p1, p2):
    if len(p1) == 3 and len(p2) == 3:
        for i in range(3):
            for c2 in PICKUPS[p1, p2]:
                new_p1 = p1[:i] + p1[i+1:] + (c2,)
                yield p2, tuple(sorted(new_p1))
        return
    for c2 in PICKUPS[p1, p2]:
        new_p1 = tuple(sorted(p1 + (c2,)))
        yield p2, new_p1

def raw_score(S):
    p1, p2 = S
    w1 = len(p1) == 3 and sum(p1) == 15
    w2 = len(p2) == 3 and sum(p2) == 15
    if w1 and w2:
        return 0
    elif w1:
        return 1
    elif w2:
        return -1

for S in STATES:
    score = raw_score(S)
    if score is not None:
        WL[S] = score

while True:
    modified = False
    for S in STATES:
        if S in WL:
            continue
        move_scores = [WL.get(x) for x in moves(*S)]
        if -1 in move_scores:
            WL[S] = 1
            modified = True
        if all(x == 1 for x in move_scores):
            WL[S] = -1
            modified = True
    if not modified:
        break

def droptake(old, new):
    if len(old) == len(new):
        return [x for x in old if x not in new][0], [x for x in new if x not in old][0]
    else:
        return None, [x for x in new if x not in old][0]

def describe(S, S2):
    old = S[0]
    new = S2[1]
    drop, take = droptake(old, new)
    if drop:
        return '%d->%d' % (drop, take)
    else:
        return '%d' % take

def describe_state(S):
    p1, p2 = S
    return (''.join(str(x) for x in p1) or '/')+ ' - ' + (''.join(str(x) for x in p2) or '/')

index = dict()
for i, S in enumerate(STATES):
    index[S] = i

for S in STATES:
    wins = []
    loses = []
    draws = []
    score = raw_score(S)
    if score is not None:
        if score != 0:
            print(describe_state(S), ' :', '<WON>' if score == 1 else '<LOST>')
        continue
    for S2 in moves(*S):
        score = WL.get(S2)
        if score == -1:
            wins.append(describe(S, S2))
        elif score == 1:
            loses.append(describe(S, S2))
        else:
            draws.append(describe(S, S2))
    print(describe_state(S), ' :', 'WINS:', ', '.join(wins) or 'none', '| LOSSES:', ', '.join(loses) or 'none', '| DRAWS:', ', '.join(draws) or 'none')
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you conclude 1769 states ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust the number of states per card-count for the player on move vs the other player are: (0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 8, (1, 1): 56, (1, 2): 168, (2, 2): 420, (2, 3): 560, (3, 3): 560. But there's 4 of the 3-card vs 3-card states that are impossible: both player's cards add up to 15 -- (168,357), (267,348), (348,267), (357,168). Those impossible states are not listed in the solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust thanks for your comment - I found and fixed a bug because of it. (States with 2-cards vs a winning 3-cards were handled incorrectly if the 2-card player could pick up a card that would also let them "win").

Comment: Thanks for the details. Yep, I was about to comment on the case of a player winning with just two cards, which stops the game.